# Vue.js & Nuxt cache

Tags: vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js, nginx-reverse-proxy, pm2

We are hosting a nuxt application with nginx as a reverse proxy and pm2. The application was hosted on domain.com and after a few months transferred to subdomain.domain.com. The domain.com was pointed to completely different server (with apache) and should serve different type of project.

On second server that now holds domain.com, the redirection is made to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) (Wordpress project).
What started to happen is that if previously visited domain.com, it still shows cached app even tho the domain.com now serves Wordpress project. We though the cache would expire but even after week + it still holds the copy of an app. The server has set redirection from non-www to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) but that redirection never happens and it still loads app from cache.

So far only if you clear cached data from browser (including service workers) the domain.com loads new project.
Is there a way to force the browser to reload cache?

Thanks.

The headers are set to no cache and non-www domain pointed to completely different server.
The redirection was made from non-www to www and cache was cleared from both servers (Cloudflare)

Comment: I wonder if Cloudflare is to blame. Are you using Cloudflare as a DNS proxy?

Comment: Hello, yeh we are behind Cloudflare proxy. Tried to switch to DNS only but the issue remains. The only thing so far that worked is to clear site data on browsers that previously visited the site.